# Is it possible to use a bottom drawer widget without pulling it away in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am currently working in a page where I have to show a list of apps in the device which should be **half a screen only**, for that i have a used a bottom drawer widget to display that ,
the main problem is every time i open the app **it needs to get pulled**, i don't want to do it so can some help me to display the apps without pulling the bottom drawer widget ? or else is there any other widget to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try bottom modal sheet or draggableScrollableSheet which has a min size

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

draggableScrollableSheet

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('DraggableScrollableSheet'),
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: scrollController,
                itemCount: 25,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need a title too for the lists , is it possible to add the title for the lists ?\

Comment: Of course.. wrap the `listview` with a `column` widget, add `shrinkwrap: true` to the listview. As the first child of column add the header(Row widget or any widget of your choice). Then wrap the `column` with `SingleChildScrollView`.  Also add physics: `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the listview

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DraggableScrollableSheet` with  `minChildSize: .5,` on this case.

```dart
return Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: DraggableScrollableSheet(
  minChildSize: .5,
  maxChildSize: 1,
  builder: (context, scrollController) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Center(
          child: Text("Title"),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            itemCount: 25,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(title: Text('Item $index'));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
));
```

More about [`DraggableScrollableSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

Comment: It should contain a title too, this does not have any title , is it possible to add ?

Comment: Wrap ListView with Expanded , then wrap with Column to include another widget